# How do I merge 2 NSSets in objective-c?

Tags: cocoa, nsset

How do I merge 2 NSSets in objective-c ?

I can't find solution on google.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is fairly easy to spot among NSSet's methods:

```
- (NSSet *) setByAddingObjectsFromSet:(NSSet*) other;
```

Answer (score 5):

If one of the sets is an `NSMutableSet` then you can use a union operation, like in the following example:

```
// Create / Get the sets
NSMutableSet *firstSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:@[@"1", @"2"]];
NSSet *secondSet = [NSSet setWithArray:@[@"3",@"4"]];

// Add missing values from the second set to the first set
[firstSet unionSet:secondSet];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this if you are merging two set.

```
NSSet *mergedSet = [set setByAddingObjectsFromSet:set];
```

If you are merging array into set then you can use

```
NSSet *mergedSet = [set setByAddingObjectsFromArray:array];
```